# Javascript cannot stub with sinon.stub

Tags: javascript, html, testing, sinon, stub

sinon.stub doesnt work...

So I installed sinon and I try to stub an object's method with fake arguments. But after the stub Im calling the object's method and it's not calling at all. Not only the fake args even the object's method doesnt work at all after stubbing.

printer.js

```
export class Printer {
constructor(name){
  this.name = name;
}

info(obj){
console.log(obj.name)
}
```

require and import work both because I use babel but thats not the problem

test.js

```
import { Printer } from 'printer.js';
const sinon = require('sinon');
let printer = new Printer("Samsung");
```

```
test('stubbing', async () => {
  let fakeArg = {name: "Fake", Made: 2010}
    
  let stub = sinon.stub(printer, "info");
  stub.withArgs(fakeArg);
    
  printer.info({name: 'Samsung', Made: 2000})

  //info method is never calling after stubbing. 

})
```

The printer.info method has stopped working at all after stubbing. If I delete the stubbing its work perfectly.

What did I do wrong?

### Edit:

So
My test file after tried spying:

```
test('stubbing', () => {
    let fakeArg = {name: "Fake", Made: 2010}

    let spy = 
     sinon
     .spy(printer, "info")
     spy.withArgs(fakeArg)
```

And I would like to do here one thing:

```
printer.info({name: 'Samsung', Made: 2000})
/* So I call printer.info with this parameter but I would like to overwrite this parameter with spy to fakeArgs. So I want the spy to overwrite the 
{name: 'Samsung', Made: 2000} parameter to the fakeArgs parameter.

So when I call this method above I expect to be called with the fakeArgs parameter and not with what I given to it. */
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how `sinon.stub()` works, it will **replace `object.method` with a stub function.** This means it will replace the original implementation with a stub implementation. The original implementation of `printer.info` method is `console.log(obj.name)` in your case.

You should use a spy to wrap an existing method like `sinon.spy(printer, 'info')`. This will **not** replace the original implementation but just add a spy on the method so that you can use spy API such as `spy.calledOnceWith(arg1, arg2, ...);` to assert.

Comment: Thank you! One more question. How can I manipulate the spied object with my arguments. I mean How can I do that If I call the objects method randomly It will always call with the args I manipulated with?

Comment: @jozsi Sorry, don't understand what you mean. Are you looking for `spy.withArgs(arg1[, arg2, ...]);` API?

Comment: Yes, I mean something like that. But If I do spy.withargs(fakeArg) and then I call printer.info( {name: "asd", Made: 2010}) It will give me back the object parameter I called with(name:asd) and not the manipulated parameter(fakearg)

Comment: I mean I would like to the following: Only manipulating the printer.info method with my specific parameter. And from then whenever I call printer.info while testing, It will call with my manipulated parameter. Because I imported printer obj from 'another' js file. And I would like to test that 'another' js file. And in the 'another' js file the printer.info calling with another parameters. But I want to test It with my specific parameters.

Comment: Tell me If im not explain it clear enough

Comment: @jozsi Show some code may make people understand

Comment: @jozsi You should edit your question.

Comment: I edited it, tell me If something I explained badly.